# How to get the actual integer value from an array list

Tags: java, arraylist, towers-of-hanoi

I am using an ArrayList of ArrayLists for a data structure to play a game of towers of hanoi.  The game is constructed and initialized as follows:

```
private ArrayList<ArrayList> lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
private ArrayList<Integer> peg1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> peg2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
private ArrayList<Integer> peg3 = new ArrayList<Integer>();


//Constructor
public TowersOfHanoi() {

   lists.add(null);
   lists.add(peg1);
   lists.add(peg2);
   lists.add(peg3);
}

public ArrayList initializeGame(int n) {

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        peg1.add(i+1);
    }

        return peg1;
    }
}
```

I am trying to use a Boolean method to do a check and make sure the user doesn't try to move a larger disc on top of a smaller disc, however, I don't understand how I would grab the the integer value stored in the arrayList.  The integer values should serve as a way to gauge the diameter of the discs.  I.E. 1 is smaller than two is smaller than 3 etc.  This is the code I have come up with...  I believe I am just getting the indexes and not the actual values of the integers stored there.  How can I get the actual values?

```
public boolean isMoveLegal(int moveFrom, int moveTo){

  ArrayList<Integer> fromPeg = lists.get(moveFrom);
  int x = (fromPeg.remove(0)).intValue();

  ArrayList<Integer> toPeg = lists.get(moveTo);
  int y = (toPeg.get(0)).compareTo(x);

  if(x<y){

     System.out.println("illegal move");
  }

  return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you even look at the Javadocs first?

Comment: Are you aware that your `isMoveLegal()` method always returns *false*?

Comment: `remove` and `get` both return values from the list, not indexes.  As the answer says, you're not setting `y` to a value from the list, because the `compareTo` messes it up.  Also: (1) If you have an `Integer`, you can assign it to an `int` without using `intValue()`.  (This is called auto-unboxing.)  (2) Instead of `ArrayList<ArrayList>`, please use `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`.  You should not use generic types (such as `ArrayList`) without a type parameter (`Integer`), unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: @ajb  Thank you!!  I had seen but did not understand the syntax `ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>`  I am familiar with Autoboxing and did not know this was how to do the opposite.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `isMoveLegal` does not have a path where it would return `true`: the only return statement returns `false`. You should change the return statement as follows:

```
return x >= y;
```

This line is wrong too:

```
int y = (toPeg.get(0)).compareTo(x);
```

rather than getting the actual value into `y`, you are storing the result of comparison of `y` to `x`, which is *not* something you should compare to `x` again.

Additionally, your check is invasive: it removes the disks at the top of your pegs (it is apparent from your code that the top of the tower corresponds to position zero; this is unorthodox, but you can certainly make it work).

Rather than using `remove(0)`, you should use `get(0)` after checking that the peg's content is not empty.

If the "from" peg is empty, the move is invalid. If the "to" peg is empty, the move is valid. Otherwise, the regular comparison rules apply (i.e. a bigger disk cannot go on top of a smaller disk).

```
public boolean isMoveLegal(int moveFrom, int moveTo){
    ArrayList<Integer> toPeg = lists.get(moveTo);
    if (toPeg.isEmpty()) return true; // You can move anything on an empty peg
    int y = toPeg.get(0).intValue();
    ArrayList<Integer> fromPeg = lists.get(moveFrom);
    if (fromPeg.isEmpty()) return false; // No disks on the "from" peg
    int x = fromPeg.get(0).intValue();
    if(x>y){
       System.out.println("illegal move");
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  changed `fromPeg.remove(0)` to `fromPeg.get(0)` and changed the return statement, but, it is still letting me put a larger disc on a smaller one.

Answer (score 1):

This,

```
int y = (toPeg.get(0)).compareTo(x);
```

should be something like

```
int y = (toPeg.size() > 0) ? toPeg.get(0).intValue() : -1;
```

Then you can use

```
if (x > y) { // <-- the reverse of like you were, because the to peg is y.
```

Comment: `int y = (toPeg.size() > 0) ? toPeg.get(0).intValue() : -1;` is really going to throw this noob

Comment: Also, OP should not be calling remove() unless the disc is actually moved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.  That looks like a nice little bit of syntactic magic but unfortunately it is still not working.   I also tried using `fromPeg.remove(0).intValue()` storing that in `x` and using `toPeg.get(0).intValue()` storing that in `y`  That didn't work either.  Am I correct in a assuming that I am just storing the integer value of the index and not the actual integer stored in the index?  I think this is where my problem lies.

Comment: No. You are getting the actual integer value stored at index 0.

Comment: @ScaryWombat.  Yes.  Yes it did.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Thanks for the exposure to the ternary operator.  I had never used this before.

Answer (score 1):

```
public boolean isMoveLegal(int moveFrom, int moveTo){

    ArrayList<Integer> fromPeg = lists.get(moveFrom);
    if(fromPeg != null && fromPeg.size() > 0) {

        int x = fromPeg.get(0).intValue();

        ArrayList<Integer> toPeg = lists.get(moveTo);
        if(toPeg != null) {

            if(toPeg.size() == 0) {
                return true;
            } else {

                int y = toPeg.get(0).intValue();

                if(x<y){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("illegal move");

    return false;
}
```

Comment: THank you this also works.  I believe `toPeg.size()==0` can be replaced with `toPeg.isEmpty()`